# Ghost user in debian?

Tags: linux, debian, openvz

I have an openvz vps with debian, I am new to linux and the command line environment although i can setup a webserver. I have just noticed that there is a ghost user because when i execute `/usr/bin/w` it shows that there are two users logged in:

```
10:55:15 up 9 days,  4:38,  2 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT

user1   pts/0    0.0.0.0  10:54    0.00s  0.02s  0.00s w
```

user1 is me logged-in from a ssh session, so I'm not sure about the other one if it's normal in openvz or what. Any insight is useful. Thanks.

Comment: run the "last" command.